# Proxmox API returns cryptic error when creating a container with salt-cloud

Tags: proxmox, saltstack

I'm using a stock Proxmox with salt-cloud to automatically provision lxc containers. Salt's provisioning fails while attempting to create any container with this cryptic error message:

```
Can't call method "map_method_by_name" on an undefined value at
    /usr/share/perl5/PVE/RESTHandler.pm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be resolved by adding the appropriate permissions to the user accessing the API:

**Via the command-line:**

```
pveum aclmod / -user salt@pve -role PVEVMAdmin
pveum aclmod / -user salt@pve -role PVEDatastoreAdmin
```

Remember to swap `salt@pve` for your own user.

---

**Via the web interface:**

1. Make sure you're using the **Server View** and select **Datacenter**.

[image]

2. Click on the **Permissions** tab:

[image]

3. Click **Add** and from the drop-down, select **User Permission**

[image]

4. In the dialog, under 'Path', enter `/`.
5. In the 'User' drop-down, select the user salt-cloud is logging in as.
6. Under 'Role', select 'PVEVMAdmin'.

[image]

7. Repeat steps 3-6 for the 'PVEDatastoreAdmin' permission also.

Comment: IMO, this answer isn't very useful.  What permissions?  Where do you set them?

Comment: Edited the answer to include some details. I tried to include images of the interface but I lack the reputation.